# Symfony2 - Execution order of test cases

Tags: symfony, netbeans-7, functional-testing, automated-tests

I'm using Symfony Functional Tests in NETBEANS. Is it possible to define the order in which order will the test cases be executed?

For example: I have "**UserTestCase**" case for testing registration of users, changing their profiles etc, and "**ForumTestCase**" for testing creation of forum posts etc. I want to run UserTestCase before ForumTestCase. Now the order is according to file names (F.. before U..)

Comment: @pomaxa has the answer.  Just wanted to point out that having test cases depend on each other is generally a bad idea.  I suspect your ForumTestCase probably depends on data provided by the UserTestCase. But in the long run you will probably find it worthwhile to make the ForumTestCase use data fixtures so it can run stand alone.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, good point actually...

Comment: I edited the question a bit, because I found out, that Netbeans (which I am using) ignores some setups in phpunit.xml and therefore the answer below didn't work for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Netbeans for the development and I was wondering for a long time, why this didn't work for me.

Then I found out, that Netbeans simply ignores folder definitions and the order of execution defined in <kbd>phpunit.xml</kbd>

See here: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=199072

Answer (score 5):

You need to define order of tests in your phpunit.xml as described in [docs](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/organizing-tests.html)

example:

```
<phpunit>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Object_Freezer">
      <file>Tests/Freezer/HashGenerator/NonRecursiveSHA1Test.php</file>
      <file>Tests/Freezer/IdGenerator/UUIDTest.php</file>
      <file>Tests/Freezer/UtilTest.php</file>
      <file>Tests/FreezerTest.php</file>
      <file>Tests/Freezer/StorageTest.php</file>
      <file>Tests/Freezer/Storage/CouchDB/WithLazyLoadTest.php</file>
      <file>Tests/Freezer/Storage/CouchDB/WithoutLazyLoadTest.php</file>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```